# How to find the list of products ordered by a customer that is greater than a certain number?

Tags: sqlite

How do  I select the products ordered by customers that have their series greater than 3000?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the digits first from Eg. RTX 3070 -> 3070 and compare it in your where clause.

EG.
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT p where CAST(SUBSTRING('RTX 3070', PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'RTX 3070'), LEN('RTX 3070')) AS int) < CAST(SUBSTRING(p.name, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', p.name), LEN(p.name)) AS int)

Comment: Hello, I'm getting no such functions for patindex and len? I am quite new to SQLite.

Comment: INSTR(string, substring) for patindex, length for the LEN function, please try in SQLite perspective

Comment: you can remove the customerID in where clause as it is only returns 1 arg and trying to filter with greater than the value